# How can we achieve compile time type checking with generic bean in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following reproducible code

```java
// controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/print")
public class PrintController2 {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectPrintService<String> objectPrintService;

    @GetMapping
    public String print() {
        objectPrintService.print("Hello World");
        return "Hello World Printed!";
    }
}


// service
public interface ObjectPrintService<T> {
    void print(T object);
}


// service implemention
@Service
public class ObjectPrintServiceImpl<T extends Student> implements ObjectPrintService<T> {
    @Override
    public void print(T object) {
        System.out.println("Student => Name: " + object.getName() + ", Age: " + object.getAge());
    }
}


// student POJO
@Data // lombok @data
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Student(String john, int i) {
        this.name = john;
        this.age = i;
    }
}
```

I have defined a bean `ObjectPrintServiceImpl` of `ObjectPrintService` type and the type argument is `T extends Student`. So, i am assuming that `ObjectPrintServiceImpl` will work with `Student` type only.

You can see that in controller i have provided `String` as type argument to `ObjectPrintService`. Ideally spring boot application shouldn’t start as there is no such bean of `ObjectPrintService` which can work with `String` type.

But spring boot application is starting fine without any error/warning. When i am requesting to http://localhost:8080/print then i am getting `ClassCastException`.

```js
// part of stack trace 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.sr.cbapi.test2.Student (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.sr.cbapi.test2.Student is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6d9cfd03)\n\tat com.sr.cbapi.test2.ObjectPrintServiceImpl.print
```

Is there any way to achieve compile time checking, not at run time.

Answer (score -2):

```java
public interface ObjectPrintService {
    void print(T object);
}

@Service public class ObjectPrintServiceImpl implements ObjectPrintService {
    @Override public void print(Student object) {
        System.out.println("Student => Name: " + object.getName() + ", Age: " + object.getAge());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some information other than just code. A good answer explains what the code does and why

Comment: This code won’t even compile.